# Win32_WindowsProductActivation ProductID equivalent in Software Licensing Classes

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, wmi

I have a piece of old code that used a query using **WQL** to get in from the **Win32_WindowsProductActivation** class.

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_WindowsProductActivation
```

It then itterated over it and essentialy got the ProductID string using

```
hres = pclsObj->Get("ProductID", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
```

and

```
return WideString(vtProp.bstrVal);
```

I wanna clean this up a bit and also wanted to make it function in Windows 7 and noticed that the support for the Win32_WindowsProductActivation class was dropped in Windows Vista. I also read that similar functionality is now provided by the Software Licensing Classes. How would the above look with its Software Licensing Classes equivalent?

I don't seem to see which exat field would return the same value. Guessing *ProductKeyID* of the *SoftwareLicensingProduct* class. But there are others that sound like likley candidates to :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ProductID property of the Win32_WindowsProductActivation states

> String of 20 characters separated by hyphens in the format,
>   xxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx. This is the same product ID that is displayed
>   under the General tab of the System Properties dialog in Control
>   Panel.

Now if you check the value of the `ProductKeyID` property of the [SoftwareLicensingProduct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc534596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class in Windows 7, this not match with the ProductID of the System Properties dialog.

The solution is use the `SerialNumber` property of the [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this works in Windows XP, Vista and 7 (and Windows server editions too)